# Getting an error when I try to use Stable Diffusion with miniconda3

Tags: python, stable-diffusion

Today I searched online for a way to get an AI Image Generator on my own PC. So far I followed every step, that I found on an online article. Up until the point, where I input, what kind of image I wanted to create. After I entered the desired input, I got the following messages:

```
File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 22, in <module>
    from diffusers.pipelines.stable_diffusion.safety_checker import StableDiffusionSafetyChecker
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\diffusers\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .pipelines import OnnxRuntimeModel
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\diffusers\pipelines\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .dance_diffusion import DanceDiffusionPipeline
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\diffusers\pipelines\dance_diffusion\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pipeline_dance_diffusion import DanceDiffusionPipeline
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\diffusers\pipelines\dance_diffusion\pipeline_dance_diffusion.py", line 21, in <module>
    from ..pipeline_utils import AudioPipelineOutput, DiffusionPipeline
  File "D:\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\diffusers\pipelines\pipeline_utils.py", line 67, in <module>
    from transformers.utils import SAFE_WEIGHTS_NAME as TRANSFORMERS_SAFE_WEIGHTS_NAME
ImportError: cannot import name 'SAFE_WEIGHTS_NAME' from 'transformers.utils' (D:\miniconda3\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\__init__.py)
```

What exactly did I do wrong on this one?

Comment: How did you install `transformers` library? Can you link the article?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.